# jQuery: Read all domain cookies if you don't know their names

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, jquery-plugins

I'm using the jQuery cookie plugin to read/write/delete cookies. I'm using cookies to store points on a graph that the user plotted on top of a canvas. I'm allowing the user to store the plotted points along with a name in the cookie, I'm also listing the saved cookies so that they can redraw their saved points on the graph.

I was originally saving and reloading the points from cookies by naming each cookie with a sequential number `$.cookie("_1")`, `$.cookie("_2")`, etc and this worked. Problems start when user deletes a cookie and the sequential numbering breaks.

I would like to save the cookie using the name that the user gives to the plotted points, so basically saving cookies with arbitrary names. If I do this **is it possible to read all domain cookies if I don't know their names?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need jQuery for this. You can read all your cookies by accessing `document.cookie` and parsing accordingly.

See an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252665/i-need-to-get-all-the-cookies-from-the-browser/252959#252959).

Comment: Yeah, thanks! Just realised this too, must remember that there's a thing called Javascript lurking under jQuery.

Comment: [Here](https://www.inkling.com/read/javascript-definitive-guide-david-flanagan-6th/chapter-20/parsing-the-document-cookies) is another example of how to parse it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about calling all domain cookies, but you could always store the cookie with a name you choose and then make the value of the cookie be "name,x,y" or something.  Just an idea as an alternative to trying to pull all domain cookies.

EDIT:

Also, [this cookies plugin wiki](http://code.google.com/p/cookies/wiki/Documentation#Get_Filtered_list_of_cookies) shows that you can easily get a filtered list of cookies.  So you could throw on an identifier to the name of the cookie `"mysite+name"` and then use `.slice` to take it back off after you get your filtered list.

Comment: Yeah, could do that, was going to rewrite the sequential numbering of cookies if the reading of all of them is not possible.

Comment: I found something that might help, so I edited my answer to show it.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to the answers already provided, you could simply use the framework the folks at Mozilla created in their `Document.cookie` documentation.

Here is how it looks:

```
/*\
|*|
|*|  :: cookies.js ::
|*|
|*|  A complete cookies reader/writer framework with full unicode support.
|*|
|*|  Revision #1 - September 4, 2014
|*|
|*|  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie
|*|  https://developer.mozilla.org/User:fusionchess
|*|
|*|  This framework is released under the GNU Public License, version 3 or later.
|*|  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0-standalone.html
|*|
|*|  Syntaxes:
|*|
|*|  * docCookies.setItem(name, value[, end[, path[, domain[, secure]]]])
|*|  * docCookies.getItem(name)
|*|  * docCookies.removeItem(name[, path[, domain]])
|*|  * docCookies.hasItem(name)
|*|  * docCookies.keys()
|*|
\*/

var docCookies = {
  getItem: function (sKey) {
    if (!sKey) { return null; }
    return decodeURIComponent(document.cookie.replace(new RegExp("(?:(?:^|.*;)\\s*" + encodeURIComponent(sKey).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=\\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$"), "$1")) || null;
  },
  setItem: function (sKey, sValue, vEnd, sPath, sDomain, bSecure) {
    if (!sKey || /^(?:expires|max\-age|path|domain|secure)$/i.test(sKey)) { return false; }
    var sExpires = "";
    if (vEnd) {
      switch (vEnd.constructor) {
        case Number:
          sExpires = vEnd === Infinity ? "; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT" : "; max-age=" + vEnd;
          break;
        case String:
          sExpires = "; expires=" + vEnd;
          break;
        case Date:
          sExpires = "; expires=" + vEnd.toUTCString();
          break;
      }
    }
    document.cookie = encodeURIComponent(sKey) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(sValue) + sExpires + (sDomain ? "; domain=" + sDomain : "") + (sPath ? "; path=" + sPath : "") + (bSecure ? "; secure" : "");
    return true;
  },
  removeItem: function (sKey, sPath, sDomain) {
    if (!this.hasItem(sKey)) { return false; }
    document.cookie = encodeURIComponent(sKey) + "=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT" + (sDomain ? "; domain=" + sDomain : "") + (sPath ? "; path=" + sPath : "");
    return true;
  },
  hasItem: function (sKey) {
    if (!sKey) { return false; }
    return (new RegExp("(?:^|;\\s*)" + encodeURIComponent(sKey).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=")).test(document.cookie);
  },
  keys: function () {
    var aKeys = document.cookie.replace(/((?:^|\s*;)[^\=]+)(?=;|$)|^\s*|\s*(?:\=[^;]*)?(?:\1|$)/g, "").split(/\s*(?:\=[^;]*)?;\s*/);
    for (var nLen = aKeys.length, nIdx = 0; nIdx < nLen; nIdx++) { aKeys[nIdx] = decodeURIComponent(aKeys[nIdx]); }
    return aKeys;
  }
};
```

Source: [developer.mozilla.org - Document.cookie - A little framework: a complete cookies reader/writer with full unicode support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie#A_little_framework_a_complete_cookies_readerwriter_with_full_unicode_support)