# browser.cookies.getAll() always returns nothing - Firefox Extension

Tags: javascript, cookies, firefox-addon-webextensions, manifest.json

I have been trying to list all browser cookies in my extension with `browser.cookies.getAll()`. At first, I thought it was a permissions issue, but my permissions appear to be set correctly. Here is my code:

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "CookieExample",
    "version": "0.1",
    
    "applications": {
        "gecko": {
            "id": "cookieexample@example.com"
        }
    },
    
    "permissions": [
        "cookies",
        "webNavigation",
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking",
        "<all_urls>"
    ],
    
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["cookies.js"]
    }        
}
```

**cookies.js**

```
browser.cookies.getAll({}, function(cookies) {
    console.log(cookies);
});
```

The console simply logs `[]` as the return value. I don't know where I've gone wrong or if it's a problem with the browser. [Cookie Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/a-cookie-manager/) works just fine and lists all browser cookies without a hitch. Looking into its source code, the only difference is that it uses a cookie store ID to query for cookies, whereas I used nothing.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `browser.cookies.getAllCookieStores` to get all stores, match them with the id of the tab you want the cookies from (a store knows all it's tabs in the `tabIds` property), then pass the `storeId` to `browser.cookies.getAll`.

Comment: Is it only possible to get cookies from open tabs? Not just all cookies in the browser?

Comment: cookies are stored per domain, not per tab.
you can ask each tab for it's URL and query all cookies for that specific URL.

Comment: `match them with the id of the tab you want the cookies from`: how to get all cookies regardless if any tab is open? It would be interesting to find a solution without requiring anything about tabs.

Comment: Cookies aren't tab related at all. In order to retrieve cookies for a specific request you need to specify a target URL and from wich cookie store they should be taken (There are two: The common one and the store for private browsing). If you want to retrieve all cookies in any cookie store you need to use `getAllCookieStores` to enumerate the stores and the use `getAll` to retrieve all cookies in that store. If you don't specify the cookie store in `getAll` the browser will automatically select one, but I don't know how the browser decides whether to use the common or private one.

Answer (score 0):

from [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies/getAll)

```
function logCookies(cookies) {
  for (let cookie of cookies) {
    console.log(cookie.value);
  }
}

var gettingAll = browser.cookies.getAll();
gettingAll.then(logCookies);
```

Answer (score 0):

**browser.cookies.getAll() always returns nothing**

there are few javascripts functions(methods) which are not compatible with safari and firefox.
one of the them is **cookieStore.getAll()**
in order to use them we can use
**const allCookies = document.cookie.split(';');**