# How to clean Firefox's browsing data and specific cookies only, from a browser extension?

Tags: firefox, cookies, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, browser-extension

We can delete Chrome's browsing data from an extension with:

```
chrome.browsingData.remove({"since": (new Date()).getTime() - 3600 * 24 }, {
  "appcache": true, "cache": true, "cacheStorage": true, "cookies": true, "downloads": true,
  "fileSystems": true, "formData": true, "history": true, "indexedDB": true, "localStorage": true,
  "passwords": true, "serviceWorkers": true, "webSQL": true }, function () { });
```

**How is it possible to do the same in Firefox, and specify which cookies to delete / which cookies to keep?** (either with a cookies-to-be-removed list or cookies-to-be-kept list)

More specifically, is there a way to use [`browser.browsingData.removeCookies`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/browsingData/removeCookies) or [`browser.cookies.remove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies/remove) to remove **all cookies except those from certain domains**?

Comment: browser.browsingData.removeCookies, also browser.cookies.getAll may be useful.

Comment: Use the remove method in browser.cookies API.

Comment: I don't have it. Try searching.

Comment: Use getAll and then iterate through the list and delete each matching cookie.

Comment: @wOxxOm Using `browser.cookies.getAll({}, ...)` returns  an empty list, exactly like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51911443/browser-cookies-getall-always-returns-nothing-firefox-extension. How do you usually do it? Thanks.

Comment: Without seeing an [MCVE](/help/mcve) I would guess you don't have host permissions in manifest.json.

Comment: @wOxxOm [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51911443/browser-cookies-getall-always-returns-nothing-firefox-extension) is a full MCVE I have this exact same problem with `getAll`. I have `cookies` permissions enabled.

Comment: I don't know. That code, assuming you use it verbatim and the browser has cookies, must work.

Comment: @wOxxOm Are you sure that code asks for all the cookies of the browser or only those from current tab? I'd like all cookies from any website (even if no tab is open).

Comment: Yes, I'm positive.

Comment: Note that by "host permissions" I meant `"<all_urls>"` not `cookies`.

Comment: @wOxxOm Now that I can log the cookies with `console.log(cookie);` I have these attributes: `{domain: ".youtube.com", expirationDate: 1234, firstPartyDomain: "", hostOnly: false, httpOnly: true, name: "SSID", partitionKey: null, path: "/", sameSite: "no_restriction", secure: true, session: false, storeId: "firefox-default", value: "abcdefg"}`, I don't see an ID for this cookie. How can I delete *this* precise cookie with [`browser.cookies.remove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies/remove)? There is no identifier to this precise cookie.

Comment: The id is `name`.

Comment: @wOxxOm name is not a unique id, is that right? There can be a cookie named `lastseen` on `example.com`, and `lastseen` on `youtube.com`.

Comment: name + URL is unique.

Comment: Ok something like `browser.cookies.remove({name: cookie.name, name: cookie.name});` in the loop of all non-whitelisted cookies?

Comment: Not two names but `name` + `url`.

Comment: Yes sorry wrong copy paste!

Comment: Last thing @wOxxOm: things still remain after `remove`, would you know why? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71256590/what-are-these-remaining-data-after-browser-browsingdata-remove