# What are these remaining data after browser.browsingData.remove?

Tags: javascript, firefox, cookies, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

After doing this in a Firefox extension:

```
browser.browsingData.remove({"since": 0, "originTypes": {"unprotectedWeb": true, "protectedWeb": true, "extension": true} }, {
  "cache": true,
  "cookies": false,        // I delete them separately
  "downloads": true,
  //"fileSystems": true,   // not available on FF
  "formData": true,
  "history": true,
  "indexedDB": true,
  "localStorage": true,
  "passwords": false,
  "pluginData": true,
  "serviceWorkers": true,
}, function() { 
    console.log('done');
});
```

everything is successfully deleted (history, etc.), but this is still remaining:

[image]

Why? This is not because of cookies (these website have currently 0 cookies, I double checked this).

**How to remove everything completely?**

Note: I have set `"permissions": ["storage", "browsingData", "cookies", "<all_urls>"]` in the manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/browsingData/#type) is a list of the DataTypeSets. For example, you missed "appcache". Hope that helps, otherwise have you already looked under *about:cache*?

Comment: In Firefox, there seems to be no "appcache" DataTypeSet: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/browsingData/DataTypeSet

Comment: @Basj that might not the best example, because firefox disabled "appcache" by default. But thinks like these, that you can't delete programmatically in firefox, are the missing ones. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem a solution, but in most cases this shouldn't be a problem. Firefox only title them with "Offline Website Data" https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/clear-cookies-and-site-data-firefox#w_clear-all-cookies-and-keep-other-data At least that setting erased everything else for me, but I couldn't find a proper description.