# ARRAffinitySameSite cookies block my other cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, axios, azure-web-app-service

I've deployed my app on Azure App Service and I know that Azure provides ARRAffinitySameSite cookie, but also I have another cookie for auth purposes, let's call it 'AUTH_COOKIE'.

Locally, I pass AUTH_COOKIE and I see them in request header (because I don't have any other cookies), but on my published app, I have two cookies: AUTH_COOKIE and ARRAffinitySameSite and my request doesn't want set to AUTH_COOKIE instead of ARRAffinitySameSite.
How I can fix it?

```
return axios.get(`someUrl`, { params: { someParam}, withCredentials: true, headers: { 'Cookie': document.cookie } });
```

Comment: The `ARRAffinity` and `ARRAffinitySameSite` cookies are set by the Azure infrastructure to help load balance your application. If your app isn't scaled to multiple instances, or doesn't use in-process session (for example) you can disable the affinity cookie from the App Service Configuration blade (under General Settings). As this cookie is sent with the `HttpOnly` flag, it can only be read server-side, and so shouldn't normally be visible from client-side code. Ordinarily, any cookies that exist on the browser are sent with requests from either the browser or JS code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## ARRAffinitySameSite is a secure cookie, we cannot read it by javascript.

[image]

For more details, please read below post and pic.

[1. How to read a HttpOnly cookie using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064318/how-to-read-a-httponly-cookie-using-javascript)

[2. I need to get all the cookies from the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252665/i-need-to-get-all-the-cookies-from-the-browser)

[image]

**If you want to use `ARRAffinitySameSite` value, the code below is an alternative.**

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's not the `Secure` flag that's stopping JS from reading it, but the `HttpOnly` flag. That means it can only be read by the receiving servers, and not the client side code. `Secure` mandates that the cookie can only be sent to pages using a secure transport (i.e. HTTPS).